# Как декодировать юникод в SQL запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode

Есть CУБД MySQL.
В текстовом поле лежит следующее значение:

```
{"error_message":"\u0423\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442 \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d"}
```

Существует ли в MySQL встроенная функция, которая в результате запроса распакует данную строку в «человекочитаемый» текст?

По аналогии с `echo -e` в `bash`:

```
$ echo -e '{"error_message":"\u0423\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0441\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442 \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d"}'
> {"error_message":"Указанный транспорт не найден"}
```

Comment: Если использовать PHP, можно сделать `json_encode(json_decode($jsonString), JSON_UNESCAPE_UNICODE)`

Comment: Вот нашел еще средствами MySQL https://gist.github.com/joni/2956080

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062330/mysql-decode-unicode-to-utf-8-function

Comment: Большое спасибо всем. Я прочитал, что встроенных методов в MySQL нет, но можно написать свою функцию. Этого пока достаточно.